# Storing multiple values in single SQL row

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, configuration

I'm trying to modelize a configuration table for my application, and I'd like to have your opinion on how to store multiple values for a configuration value.

For example, how to store the available languages? How to store the allowed files extensions, etc.?

I'd like to have a field `key` and a field `value` in my table `configuration`, but I have multiple ways of storing the value:

- Serializing a PHP array and storing this in one row,
- Storing all values separated by a comma, like this `1,4,9,42`
- Having multiple rows with the same `key` but different `values`. I don't see how I could get this working, it would be very unusable...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Where will you store the database configuration? Did you consider not storing application config in the DB?

Comment: I meant to store my website configuration in my database, under a table named 'configuration'. Sorry if this was unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside any discussion of whether or not this is a good idea, many people do this. A very common approach is to have a 'blob' field on a 'configuration' table and store your data in JSON format. You'll serialize and deserialize yourself but that's no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store your configuration in database (it's **not recommended**, but it makes sense if you have many instances of your application) - let's analyze it:

1. Approach with storing multiple rows with same key - let's forget about it ;)
2. Storing many values separated by `,` - that one would make some problems if you'll  need to store value with coma (for example: `10,000` as ten thousand). Then you'll need to modify it to store values like in CSV file encapsulated with `"`.
3. Best idea - **storing serialized PHP values**. As your app is written in PHP that would be the best *native* method. Using this approach would be as easy as:

   $configValue=unserialize(getMyValueFromDb("myKey"));
   //or saving it after change
   $configValue="new value";
   saveMyValueToDb(serialize($configValue));

Also - PHP `serialize` and `unserialize` take care about escaping values and convert it properly so you don't need to worry about some coma-separated-string wrongly split with `explode`.